# Converting String to Double in Java without using parse?

Tags: java, string, double

Is it possible to do such a thing? No loops, none of that either. Just very basic stuff. To get a perspective, just using the material on Chapters 1 and 2 from Absolute Java 5th edition.

Comment: Use `BigDecimal`.

Comment: No loops? Well... it might be possible, but ugly.

Comment: `Double.valueOf("1.0")` surely works

Comment: Doing it _correctly_ is _extremely_ difficult without using built-in functions, but you can always look at how `parseDouble` is itself implemented.  Doing it "sort of right" is quite tractable.

Comment: We can't use BigDecimal nor valueOf. Yup, no loops. How ugly does it get?

Comment: And what about `new Double(String)`?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the requirement of no loops, since a `String` is, in essence, an array of characters. If one cannot use a loop over the `String` in any form, then the only approach I see is recursion, but that is hardly "basic stuff". As an aside, I really hate professors rejecting the standard libraries and OO approach of Java.

Comment: Ernest Kiwele, neither that.

Comment: KevinO, by loop I (well the professor) meant using booleans for it to run over and over until it stops. We can't use it until we cover it (in a week or so). Yeah, I too don't get why we deal with such things if we're going to use a simpler method in a few days. That way, we could also cover more material in the book.

Answer (score 2):

If you want something without loops and something simple.

```
double a= Double.valueOf("123.3");
```

or use BigDecimal

```
BigDecimal qwe = new BigDecimal("123.3");
```

But in the end even the constructor of BigDecimal uses a loop for parsing the String to a Double. So my suggest don't try to re make the wheel and use the Java Libraries.